# Diatomic Partition Function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, partition-function

Given the following Hamiltonian:

$H = \frac { 1 } { 2 m } \left( \left| \mathbf { p } _ { 1 } \right| ^ { 2 } + \left| \mathbf { p } _ { 2 } \right| ^ { 2 } \right) + \frac { \kappa } { 2 } \left| \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } - \mathbf { r } _ { 2 } \right| ^ { 2 }$

How can I compute the partition function for the interactions? I know that I would need to do this integral:

$Z_{int} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3x_1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3x_2 \hspace{0.1cm} exp(-\beta \frac { \kappa } { 2 } \left| \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } - \mathbf { r } _ { 2 } \right| ^ { 2 })$.

My issue is that I am not sure about how to perform this integral. Can I do an ansatz such as $\xi = \mathbf { r } _ { 1 } - \mathbf { r } _ { 2 }$?

Comment: I think that'd be a very good idea!